# how to diagnose 404 not found error nginx on docker?

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, laradock

I'm trying to make working out laradock (docker+laravel)
following: https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock instructions

I installed docker + cloned laradock.git
 laradock folder is located at 
/myHD/...path../www/laradock
at the same level I have my laravel projects
/myHD/...path../www/project01

I edited laradock/docker-compose.xml

```
### Laravel Application Code Container ######################

volumes_source:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
        - ../project01/:/var/www/laravel
```

After this, bu I'm not sure it this is how to reload correctly after editing docker-file, I did:

```
 docker-compose up -d nginx mysql
```

now since I have a nginx error 404 not found: how can I debug the problem ?

Additional info:

I entered the machine via bash:

```
 docker-compose exec  --user=laradock workspace bash
```

but I cant find

```
 /etc/nginx/... path (nginx folder doesn't exists !?!?)
```

Comment: Hi @koalaok, try using the below command to access your Nginx container;
```docker-compose exec nginx bash```

Comment: For me, the problem was that I should have left `APP_CODE_PATH_HOST=../` as it was in `~/laradock/.env` because in my `~/laradock/nginx/sites/default.conf` I had set `root /var/www/tt/public;`.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing your nginx is not located in the workspace container, it resides on a separate container, You've executed the following: 
    `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql`

That would probably only run nginx and mysql containers, not your php-fpm container. Also the path to you volume is important as the configurations in you nginx server depends on this.

To run php-fpm,  add php-fpm or something similar to the docker-compose up command, check out what this is called in your docker-compose.yaml file e.g
    `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpfpm`

To assess you nginx container first of all execute

```
 `docker ps -a`
```

From the list, look for the ID of your nginx container, before running

```
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
```

This should then give you assess to your nginx container to make the required changes.

Or without directly accessing the container, simply make changes in the nginx configuration file, look for 'server' and the 'root' change the root from `var/www/laravel/public` to the new directory  `/project01/public`.

Execute the command to bring down your containers

```
docker-composer down
```

Star over again with

```
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpfpm
```

Give it a go

Comment: thanks for your answer. But: phpfpm is php-fpm, also your solution is not working for me.

Comment: Yh, which ever way (phpfpm or php-fpm) whichever way its written. Try sudo chmod -R 775 on your storage directory in Laravel